# exim4 says "Warning: purging the environment" even though add/keep_environment are set

Tags: debian, exim

Recent versions of exim4 added `add_environment` and `keep_environment` to the config. If those are missing, exim4 sends a warning to STDERR.

In my configuration, both of those variables are set to blank:

```
add_environment =
keep_environment =
```

This is a valid configuration. It's working on all of my servers, except for one, where it sends out the warning.

Working server:

```
$ exim4 -bP | grep environment
add_environment =
keep_environment =
```

Non-working server:

```
$ exim4 -bP | grep environment
LOG: MAIN
  Warning: purging the environment.
 Suggested action: use keep_environment.
add_environment =
keep_environment =
```

The configuration is the same on both servers. Both servers are running the latest version of Debian (8.7/jessie) and they're both running the same version of exim: `Exim version 4.84_2 #2 built 02-Jan-2017 18:43:31`

Answer (score 1):

`exim4 -bP` will only show you currently used values, including the the ones exim4 itself set up to defaults after outputing the warnings.

You should check with `grep -r keep_environment /etc/exim4` to see if it is indeed active in your config file. It should be in `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf` if you use that. If you have `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf`  but the option is in `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template`, you may need to add it manually or use `update-exim4.conf(8)`.

You can find more info [here](https://tronche.com/wiki/Exim_keep_environment)

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell if an option is not set or has no value from `exim -bP` output. Since the latter simply [iterates](https://github.com/Exim/exim/blob/exim-4.92/src/src/readconf.c#L2765-L2770) all the [available](https://github.com/Exim/exim/blob/exim-4.92/src/src/readconf.c#L31) options and prints their values.

Most likely one of the servers has `keep_environment` option in its config. Places to check are `/etc/exim4` and `/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated`.

The option was introduced to circumvent a certain [security threat](https://www.exim.org/static/doc/CVE-2016-1531.txt). The fix was made in `4.86.2`. But also backported to `4.84.2`. Both [Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/exim4) and [Stretch](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/exim4) have it. It cleans the environment according to `keep_environment`, `add_environment` options. If `keep_environment` is not set, it logs a warning and suggests to add it. Since `exim` might be configured in a way that needs to keep some environment variables. Which is not the case on Debian with the default config. So on Debian normally it can be set to empty value.

And at some [point](https://salsa.debian.org/exim-team/exim4/blob/09_stretch/debian/debconf/conf.d/main/02_exim4-config_options#L210-215) the option was [added](https://salsa.debian.org/exim-team/exim4/commit/5fbee94e) to the [config](https://salsa.debian.org/exim-team/exim4/commit/27427b46) (`4.87--RC6-3`). But it was in Debian Stretch. That's unlikely to be backpoirted to Jessie, since it is no security issue.

The solution is to add it to `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros` manually:

```
keep_environment =
```

Then:

```
update-exim4.conf
systemctl reload exim4
```

Answer (score 0):

That is just an annoying and harmless bug in the latest releases and will be removed sooner or later. Just ignore it.

Comment: What a crap, bugs all over.

Comment: No, it's not a bug, and don't ignore it. Add `keep_environment=` to your `exim4.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

That warning is not a bug, it's a good security feature.

Unless you know exactly what you're doing, you *want* the environment to be purged; you don't want some random user's environment leaking through Exim into the environment of piped commands, where it could be used to perform a privilege escalation.

But because this is a new feature, it's not enforced by default, because it might break existing use cases. So it's a warning, for now. In future enforcement will probably be turned on by default. In the meantime you should check your piped scripts.

If it continues to warn after you've set `keep_environment=` and restarted the daemon, then that's a bug, but not otherwise.